# Why are new instances of this javascript obj inheriting other instance properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance

I've built a BaseModel class that all of our Models inherit from. I'm running into an issue where new instances of TestModel (below) are maintaining properties from other previously instantiated models.

Why is this? What am I'm doing wrong?

```
var util = require('util');

var ModelBase = function(request, params, definition) {
  this.request = request;

  this.def = definition.schema ? definition.schema : {};

  if(params && typeof params === 'object' && !Array.isArray()) {
    this.set(params);
  }
};

ModelBase.prototype.... // a lot more proto methods in ModelBase

// TestModel inherits from ModelBase
var TestModel = function(request, params) {
  ModelBase.call(this, request, params, MOCK_MODEL_DEFINITION);
};

util.inherits(TestModel, ModelBase);

var mdl = new TestModel(MOCK_REQUEST, { a: 'A' });
var mdl2 = new TestModel(MOCK_REQUEST);

console.log(mdl.toObject()); // { a: 'A' }
console.log(mdl2.toObject()); // { a: 'A' } - should be empty
```

***Edit***: Here are some other things I've tried that aren't working:

```
var TestModel = function(request, params) {
  return new ModelBase(request, params, MOCK_MODEL_DEFINITION);
};

// move the base constructor logic to an init func
var TestModel = function(request, params) {
  this.init(request, params, MOCK_MODEL_DEFINITION);
};
```

Comment: You aren't creating a `new` `ModelBase` object - you are just calling the same one in a different scope (note: I was not the downvote).

Comment: So how do I init a new ModelBase but keep context? That's def the issue so if you submit an answer, I'll prob accept it.

Comment: @Adam it appears doing `new ModelBase` instead of call exhibits the same behavior so I'm stumped.

Comment: What is that `this.set(params)` method? I get an error when trying your code.

Comment: Your notions of inheritance are a little odd, but the code above should not have the behavior you describe. I'm guessing you edited it to show us, but I tested what you've shown and the two instances are distinct. Of course, I had to mock `set` because I have no idea what that does.

Comment: Complete working example of the issue with a `set` and `toObject` defined: http://jsfiddle.net/K4RM5/ any and all help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all of your objects initialize their `def` field from the same source. `ModelBase` is called like this in the `TestModel` constructor:

```
ModelBase.call(this, request, params, MOCK_MODEL_DEFINITION);
```

So in *all cases* `def` is set to the value of `MOCK_MODEL_DEFINITION.schema` which is an object defined as `{ a: { validate: 'validation obj here' } }` any change on this object is going to be shared by all `TestModel` objects.

This can easily be tested by adding the following test to your code:

```
console.log(mdl.def === mdl2.def);
```

This will show `true`. This indicates that `mdl.def` and `mdl2.def` are not *two* objects sharing the same values but that they are the *same exact object*.

I see two solutions

#### Decouple your schema from your data

Right now you are storing the schema you use to validate your data in the same structure as your data. You could keep storing your schema in `def` as you do now. But you should store the data into a different field. For instance:

```
var ModelBase = function(request, params, definition) {
  this.def = definition.schema ? definition.schema : {};
  this.data = {};
  this.set(params);
};

ModelBase.prototype.set = function(params) {
  for(var p in params) {
    this.data[p] = params[p];
  }
};
```

If your schemas are immutable then there is no problem sharing them.

#### Copy the data you use to initialize `def`

What you need to do there is initialize `def` by creating a copy of the object from which it is initialized. Basically, instead of this:

```
this.def = definition.schema ? definition.schema : {};
```

you need this:

```
this.def = definition.schema ? copy(definition.schema) : {};
```

where `copy` is whatever copy operation is appropriate for your case. Here are good questions that cover the best methods for performing shallow and deep copies:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Except there are no libs that I can find that will deepCopy functions. :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deep copy functions". ``jQuery.extend`` has no problem with functions in deep copied objects.

Comment: jQuery.extend won't work because this is server side node app. Lodash has a deepClone, but it says: 'Functions and DOM nodes are **not** cloned'. So I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: The name of the Lodash function is `cloneDeep`. What the documentation means by "**not** cloned" is that a function object is not **duplicated**. 99% of the time, this is what you want because you don't modify function objects after creation. (In other words, they are used as if they were immutable.) Do you actually have a need to modify function objects after they are created?

Comment: My schema contains Joi validations (https://github.com/spumko/joi). Those are not being cloned properly so my validations are failing.

Comment: I've added another solution in my answer which does not requiring copying schemas.

Comment: I spent the better part of this yesterday and finally resolved it using the 2nd approach. Thank you for the time you spent. Much appreciated.